# How can I draw only one char of a string, without moving its position?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I have a string : School

i'm trying to have only 1 letter of this string to show in a different color, and move this letter back and forth.

this works somewhat ; I use a string(index) and move the index with a timer, than draw the 2nd string ("S", " c", "  h", etc ) on top of the 1st.

my problem is that I cannot stack those 2 string exactly ... the space isnt the same size as the other characters.

[moving orange letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPEWI.png)

I guess I could use a Font.measureString from the part of the string "School" I want to skip, and move my orange letter according to it and tweek it depending of each letters ... but it seems a tedious way of doing this...

Is there a simpler/ better! way to do it ?

Comment: You say measuring the string before it would be a pain but how else are you supposed to be able to calculate where to place your character? I don't think it would be that tedious to write a new class to handle this functionality.

Comment: well, I'm not sure, thats why I'm asking if it doesnt already exist

Comment: Sorry that came over quite harsh. I didn't mean that XNA doesn't have another way to do this. I meant that you *have* to know the size of string before your character. I'm not at my computer but you can check to see whether or not this is possible by having a look at the following values: `font.MeasureString("school").Width`, `font.MeasureString("s").Width`, `font.MeasureString("c").Width`, `font.MeasureString("hool").Width`. If the latter 3 add up to being equal to the first, then you at least know what you want to do is easily implementable! (`Width` might actually be `Y`, I can't remember)

Comment: yea I did it with something like that, I was just wondering if there was a way to send in a full string and in a paramters or something ask to not render sections of it ... ( I was 1st trying with a scisor rectangle, and I could do it cut it horinzontally and make a different kind of visual FX, but well, it works )

Comment: Ok then: No, you can't do that via some native XNA system. Implement a class that does what you want instead! :p